# RecyclerView dropped down when another view above is visible, how to fix this?

Tags: android

The pattern of the layout is below:

---LinearLayout vertical

---LinearLayout -> contains a LinearLayout that shapes like rectangle(setVisibility-> Gone)
  ---RecyclerView -> below the above layout of rectangle

Originally, I set a slide-down animation of RecyclerView from the top of the window to a position where it gives enough space for the rectangle to show and when the animation ends the LinearLayout of rectangle is shown by invoking the method setVisibility(Visible)

Problem: when I set the rectangle visible, it is visible as expected but recycler view is dropped down the space as much as the rectangle's height, leaving blank space between the rectangle and the RecyclerView. I wonder what might cause this and how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: any code, any images? anything to show what you've tried?

Comment: visbility toggles without any animation, but yours animation takes time thats why your view animates properly but recycler immediately goes down !

Answer (score 1):

I think you may not change the position of the `RecyclerView` and only set the `visibility` of the `LinearLayout` to `visible`. Changing the `visibility` will redraw the whole layout and the layout that was `Gone` will take its needed height, so the space between the top of the recycler view and the bottom of the layout will be (animation height + layout height) and that is why there is an empty space